# VS2010 Profiler comparison report baseline/comparison values

Tags: visual-studio-2010, profiler

I have run the profiler on my web project twice and then selected the two reports and generated a comparison report. When I look at the functions, I'm seeing two rows for each function:
[image]

One line is from the baseline, and the other line is from the second profile run. Shouldn't these lines be combined to show the DELTA between the TWO? I'm seeing every function call as two seperate lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the two reports you are comparing from a website project? If so it is likely that the dynamically generated module name is different each time you collect a profile. Since we use both the function name and module name to determine if functions match, this would explain why Page_Load shows up as two different rows.

You can check this by opening up each report in Visual Studio and navigating to the 'Modules' view to determine what the module name is for Page_Load in each report.

Comment: You got it, it's a website project. So I take it there's no easy way to fix this or not have the module names be dynamically generated?

Comment: If you use a 'Web Application' project instead of a 'Web Site' project, the modules won't be dynamically generated. See MSDN for a conversion option:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx .

If that isn't an option for you, unfortunately you can't configure the diff view to ignore the module name.

Comment: thanks for the info. Can't convert this site to an app so I'll live with the problem.